# Combine Two Queries Into One Without Using Temporary Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have working results, but am wondering if there's any way I can combine these into one query without having to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monthlytables AS (select user as "user", date_format(begin_time, '%Y-%m') as "date", count(distinct date(begin_time)) as "sessions"  from user_session  group by user_id, month(begin_time)  having count(distinct date(begin_time)) < 15 order by date_format(begin_time, '%Y-%m'));

select `date`,count(`date`) from monthlytables group by `date`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  It gets all users who logged in on fewer than 20 day in a month when they logged in at least once:

```
select user month(begin_session), count(distinct date(begin_session))
from atable t
group by user, month(begin_session)
having count(distinct date(begin_session)) < 20;
```

If you want this information for a particular month, then include a `where` clause.

EDIT:

If you want a count by month, just use this as a subquery:

```
select mon, sum(cnt < 20) as num
from (select user, month(begin_session) as mon,
             count(distinct date(begin_session)) as cnt
      from atable t
      group by user, month(begin_session)
     ) t
group by mon;
```

Comment: I need it for less than 20 unique days. They can log in 50 times a day on a certain day, but if they only logged in 15 days that is what I want.

Comment: @user3299633 . . . I didn't phrase the description correctly.  This is counting the number of days.

Comment: How would I get the total number of users who logged in per month less than 20 days?